# Using md5sum for speeding up dd disk imaging, sample script: Good idea?

Tags: bash, dd, md5sum, diskimage

I was thinking of ways to have my laptop HDD backed up safely, and still being able to put the backup rapidly in use if needed.
My method would be the following: I would buy an 2.5" HDD of the same size with USB to SATA cable and clone the internal to it, when disaster strikes, I would just have to swap the HDD in the laptop for the other one and I would be good to go again.
However, I would like to avoid writing 500GB each time I want to backup my HDD, especially when I know that a fair part of it (+/- 80GB) is rarely written to, this is where the following md5sum/dd script comes to the rescue, I hope:

```
#!/bin/bash
block="1M"
end=50000
count=10

input="/dev/sda"

output="/dev/sdb"
output="/path/to/imagefile"


function md5compute()
{
    dd if=$1 skip=$2 bs=$block count=$count | md5sum - | awk '{ print $1 }'
}
for i in {0..$end}
do
    start=$(($i*$count))
    md5source=$(md5compute $input $start)
    md5destination=$(md5compute $output $start)
    if [ "$md5source" != "$md5destination" ]
    then
        dd if=$input of=$output skip=$start seek=$start count=$count conv=sync,noerror,notrunc
    fi
done
```

Now, the question part:

A) With running this, would I miss some part of the disk? Do you see some flaws?

B) Could I win some time compared to the 500GB read/write?

C) Obviously I potentially write less to the target disk. Will I improve the lifetime of that disk?

D) I was thinking of leaving count to 1, and increasing the block size.Is this good idea/bad idea?

E) Would this same script work with an image file as output?

Not being very fluent in programming, there should be plenty of room for improvement, any tips?

Thank you all...

Comment: Why do you want to roll your own instead of using something like rsync?

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Are you attempting to "compress" your data to an MD5 hash then somehow revert back from that hash?

Comment: @mb21: Could rsync be able to handle /dev/sda being one file of 500GB? I already use rsync to backup my external hdd to another one, but this external drive only contains data files, no OS like my main disk (both Win7 and Linux)

Comment: @DHT: I'm using md5sum to compare corresponding chunks in source and destination, when different, the script overwrites the chunk in the destination. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Mirroring disks will solve your problem, `man mdadm`. but mixing SATA and USB may slow down your system IO.

Comment: @ruifeng: I'm using a laptop, and the backup disk would not be permanently connected, as i understand from the manpage, mdadm would not be suitable then. Or am i missing something?

Comment: As hinted at by @mb21 , you don't want to mirror the full image of your disk (different disk models might vary slightly in size, anyway). What you really want to do is create a matching set of file systems on your external drive, then use `rsync` (or `unison` or something similar) to sync those file systems file-by-file rather than copying all the dead space and files that haven't changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Point by point answer:

1. With running this, would I miss some part of the disk?

   - no.
2. Do you see some flaws?

   - While units are differents. this implie double read at source and full read before write at destination. This will mostly improve backup time.
   - there is a little probability of having MD5 matching while differences exists. This probability is reducted by using *SHA1* or *MD256* or other harder checksum algo. but this implie more resource on both ends. (See [Birthday problem on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem))
3. Could I win some time compared to the 500GB read/write?

   - In case both units are already same, yes, because reading is generaly quicker than writting. (depending on processor, for checksum computation: this could be significant on very poor processors)
4. Obviously I potentially write less to the target disk. Will I improve the lifetime of that disk?

   - In this case, yes, but if you write only diff, this will go a lot faster and improve really you disks lifetime.
   - When disk are different, you re-write whole disk, this is not efficient!
5. I was thinking of leaving count to 1, and increasing the block size.Is this good idea/bad idea?

   - I find this globally a bad idea. Why re-inventing wheel?
6. Would this same script work with an image file as output?

   - Yes.

#### Functionnality answer.

For jobs like this, you may use `rsync`! With this tools you may

- Compress data during transfer
- copy over network
- tunneling with SSH (or not)
- transfer (an write) only modified blocks

#### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), `dd` and `md5sum`

There is a kind of command I run sometime:

```
ssh $USER@$SOURCE "dd if=$PATH/$SRCDEV |tee >(sha1sum >/dev/stderr);sleep 1" |
    tee >(sha1sum >/dev/tty) | dd of=$LOCALPATH/$LOCALDEV
```

This will do a *full read* on souce host, than a *sha1sum* **before** sending to localhost (destination), than a sha1sum to ensure transfer before writting to local device.

This may render something like:

```
2998920+0 records in
2998920+0 records out
1535447040 bytes (1.4gB) copied, 81.42039 s, 18.3 MB/s
d61c645ab2c561eb10eb31f12fbd6a7e6f42bf11  -
d61c645ab2c561eb10eb31f12fbd6a7e6f42bf11  -
2998920+0 records in
2998920+0 records out
1535447040 bytes (1.4gB) copied, 81.42039 s, 18.3 MB/s
```